# can nodejs block until something is done?

Tags: node.js, block

I want to make something should be done before doing my job:

```
registerTools();

// this should do until registerTools is done!
processJob();
```

Here is the `registerTools`

```
function registerTools() {
    extractors = fs.readdirSync(extractorPath).filter(function(extractor) {
      return extractor !== "temp";
    });

    totalExtractors = extractors.length;
    extractors.map(function(item) {
      var fullExtractorPath = path.join(extractorPath, item);
      return require(fullExtractorPath);
    }).forEach(function(extractor) {
      if (extractor.test) {
        testExtractor(extractor);
      } else {
        satisfiedExtractors++;
        registerExtractor(extractor);
      }
    });
}

var registerExtractor = function(extractor) {
    if (extractor.extensions) {
      extractor.extensions.forEach(function(ext) {
        extensionExtractors[ext] = extractor.extract;
      });
    }
};
```

Comment: You are not doing any async work. So it will block by default.

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readFileSync` does block (so does `require`, kind of), so your `registerTools` function is blocking.

Whether it is a good idea or not is debatable though.